# Custom Banding option in Microstategy dashboard in 10.7 version

Tags: microstrategy

I am new to Microstrategy. I have installed Microstrategy Desktop **10.7 version**. I am trying various options from microstrategy Tutorials(**Basic Reporting Guide PDF**). I found **Custom Banding** option is there in 9x version. I didn't find any Grid Menu or Custom Banding in 10.7 version. Can any one tell me how to get this option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was called MicroStrategy Desktop in version 9 is now called MicroStrategy Developer.

You should look for documentation for version 10+ for [MicroStrategy Desktop](http://www2.microstrategy.com/producthelp/10.4/manuals/en/AnalyticsDesktopUserGuide.pdf) or MicroStrategy Dashboard (similar functionalities but using the MicroStrategy iServer and Web interface, paid options :) ). Another name for the MicroStrategy Desktop (or web Dashboards) visualization was MicroStrategy Visual Insight.

About your question, check page 394, Dashboard Editor: Grid: Format. 
If you open the Format panel after you selected a grid you should be able to see the Show Banding option. This will only color every other row of your grid.

If you want something more advanced, like colors based on values in the cells, you should use [thresholds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KbC-2K9F6x0).

Comment: Thanks Mucio. I will go through the document